# How to limit integer values to 16bit only in SQLite fields

Tags: sqlite

I am using sqlite DB with SQLite Expert personal as the Admin tool to design and add data.

My question is, how do I limit value of INT fields to a 16bit so that user cannot add number > 65535?

Please suggest any other better SQLite admin tool if what I am using is not great.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create the table in question with a constraint;

```
CREATE TABLE Test ( col1 INT, CONSTRAINT my_limit CHECK (col1<65536) );
```

which won't let you insert numbers larger than 65535 in that column.
(you may want to remember to limit below 0 also if that's a requirement)

Sadly you [can't add a constraint to an existing table in SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/omitted.html).

Comment: thanks a lot, that worked. Btw How do I limit strings to list of pre-defined values only?

Comment: @2ndlife Just create a constraint in the same way; `create table Test (value varchar(32), CONSTRAINT my_limit CHECK (value='YES' OR value='NO'));`